# Is it possible to make a list/vector of abstract class and retain child data

Tags: c++

I know this is possible with abstract classes in java but is it also possible in c++?

make child classes with additional variables and push_back into a vector of parent class then when you pop_back the parent object cast it back to the correct child class and access its data?

Comment: you could do this, by checking the data size of the parent....within the vector list

Comment: Of course you can - `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Base>> vec;` will work. `dynamic_cast` can cast `Base->Child` pointers/references if `Base` has at least one virtual function - e.g. destructor.

Comment: @DeanVanGreunen No that won't work.

Comment: Collection of (smart) base pointers to the (probably dynamically allocated objects) objects: Yes. Collections of the objects themselves: No. I believe in Java for anything other than primitive types, you are dealing with handles to dynamically created objects and never directly with raw objects as in C++. The Java situation is roughly comparable to using a smart pointer to a dynamically allocated object in C++. In proper idiomatic C++, dynamic allocations are not used where not needed.

Comment: @Quimby Especially the destructor

Answer (score 1):

You might be surprised to learn that in C++ this works in exactly the same way as it works in Java.

The missing bit of knowledge is that there are really no such things as objects in Java, in Java every object is really a reference-counting pointer to an object, an exact equivalent of C++'s `std::shared_ptr<Class>`.

In C++ you can have a `std::vector<std::shared_ptr<AbstractClass>>` or a `std::list<std::shared_ptr<AbstractClass>>` that works exactly the same way as a vector or a list of objects works in Java.

Comment: The Java garbage collector is more complex than just reference counting. You should also mention that a virtual member is needed for C++ knowing the dynamic type.